# How can I solve this System.Web.Helpers mismatch on Azure web deploy?

Tags: .net, azure, visual-studio-2012, azure-web-app-service, assemblybinding

I don't know why I can't seem to figure this out.  I'm in a bit of DLL strong-naming hell.  Here's what's happening:

- I'm using Visual Studio 2012 RC to make an MVC4 site targeting .NET 4.0
- I'm attempting to use the Gravatar Razor helper in the `Microsoft.Web.Helpers` library
- It works on my machine, but after deploying to Azure via Git, I get the following exception on invoking the Gravatar helper:

  Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

It seems that I've got a mismatch between the version of `System.Web.Helpers` installed on the GAC of whatever's hosting my Azure site and what I'm targeting.

Here's what I've tried:

- Copy Local = true
- Hacking my own _bin_deployableAssemblies folder, since the menu option seems to be missing described on [Phil Haack's blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx)
- Removing the extended assembly information in the .csproj file for System.Web.Helpers

Also, I have the following assembly binding redirect in the web.config:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      ...
</runtime>
```

Anyone??

Comment: Have you tried the answer below? Would like to help you out with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said you tried copylocal=true, but have you ensured that the assembly is getting deployed to the server?

A potential issues:

• .gitignore has a .dll filter

I would FTP to the server and check to ensure the assembly is actually in the bin directory

Comment: +1 and accepted.  The FTP thing (which I didn't realize you could do) led me to the problem (copy local was copying the deployment server's assembly, which was 1.0.xxx and not 2.0.xxx).  I also realized my _bin_deployableAssembly folder had `Microsoft.Web.Helpers` instead of `System.Web.Helpers`; once I added the right assembly to that folder, everything worked fine.